# webApi2 Odata v3 and V4 side by side

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

How can I have odata v3 and v4 api working side by side out on the same project ?

Can the same controller be returning data in both formats ? 
Do I need to have 2 copies of the same controller - one per Odata version ?

I know this should be possible cause the official WEBAPI page says it's been designed for.

"ASP.NET Web API supports both v3 and v4 of the protocol. You can even have a v4 endpoint that runs side-by-side with a v3 endpoint." - quote from www.asp.net

Question is - how do I do that ? Any tutorials ?

Comment: Just posting a link to ASP.Net issue on this issue and code duplication https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample for side by side: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataSxSSample/, FYI. This sample has 2 copies of the same controller.

Comment: Is there any way to 're-use' the same controller ? cause they differ only by 'using' statements, and other than that, it's 100% duplicate

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you do need two set of controllers. V4 doesn't provide backward compatibility.

There is also another sample for versioning:
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataVersioningSample/

This is the right solution for you. You make the first version (~/api/v1/) for OData V3 and the second version (~api/v2/) for V4. It provides better separation.

Comment: Note that you still need to have two distinct projects: one referencing OData v3 libs, and one referencing OData v4 libs as shown in the `ODataSxSSample`.

Comment: No. You don't. I have created a single project following the same way as the link I posted. I have references to both V3 and V4 libs. It is working perfectly.

Comment: I was wondering how you install both V3 and V4 from nuget into into one project?

Comment: No you don't need NuGet for V4. For V4, you need to install OData Client Generator, which is installed from Visual Studio Tools->Extensions and Updates...  Type "Odata v4 client" in the search box and you will find it.
After it is installed, you do Add->New Item->Code (under Visual C# Items). You will find a OData Client there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the OData implementation. I know WCF supports the `OData-Version` header:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793615

that the client can use to specify the version that it wants, and WCF will act appropriately with just 1 endpoint.

WebAPI on the other hand, I do not know about, but it is probably worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the steps which are quite simple without having to download a sample, nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata for v3, and Microsoft.AspNet.OData for v4. Starting with v3 and v4 wired up with default conventions, you'll get a duplicate controller name found. From here, change your v3 default route prefix to "odata/v3" (not required but recommended), and for v4, set the default route prefix to "odata/v4" and rename your controller to MyEntityV4Controller. At this point, attempting to use route attributes to solve the error will lead to an http 406 result. Instead, create a class:

```
public class CustomControllerRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (odataPath.EdmType == null)
            return null;
        var path = odataPath.Segments.OfType<EntitySetPathSegment>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (path == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return path.EntitySetName + "V4";
    }
}
```

And use it as so:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "odatav4",
            "odata/v4",
            builder.GetEdmModel(),
            new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            routingConventions);
```

From here you'll be able to browse to odata/v3/MyEntitys and odata/v4/MyEntitys, etc.